# Proper directory permisions for module installation?

Tags: 7, installation

So I'm trying to understand the correct permissions for file directories in order to install a module. I've installed drupal, and I try to install a module, which looks like so:
[image: module installation page]

But When I click install it takes me here:

[image: update manager page]

I then wanted to test if it was permissions preventing it from installing, so I chmod'd everything to 777 in the sites folder just to see, and yes, the module then installed easily and correctly. But of course, 777 on everything is insecure, so I quickly installed drupal again from scratch. So now when I check the permissions they look like this

```
html/sites$ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 5 6226 6226 4096 Jun 17 18:38 all
dr-xr-xr-x 3 6226 6226 4096 Jul 19 20:08 default
-rw-r--r-- 1 6226 6226 2365 Jun 17 18:38 example.sites.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 6226 6226  904 Jun 17 18:38 README.txt
```

So after an installation the all folder has r-x permissions and the default has r-x as well for group and other. (A side question being, what do I make of the user and group, "6226", "4096","2365", and "904"?)

The "modules" folder, inside "all" folder where they get downloaded is also set to r-x.

```
html/sites/all$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 6226 6226 4096 Jun 17 18:38 libraries
drwxr-xr-x 2 6226 6226 4096 Jun 17 18:38 modules
drwxr-xr-x 2 6226 6226 4096 Jun 17 18:38 themes
```

I don't know if this seems right to me. Shouldn't it be able to write to the folder to download the module from an external source?

Thanks for all the feedback in advance, I look forward to hearing what people have to say.

Edit, more details:

`Linux myhostname 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`ubuntu@myhostname:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data 6226 4096 Jun 17 18:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 5     6226 6226 4096 Jun 17 18:38 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data 6226  952 Jun 17 18:38 README.txt`

Okay! So. after reinstalling and repeatedly chowning folders until I made it past that request for FTP details, I finally got it to ATTEMPT to download the file. All I had to do after a fresh install was `sudo chown www-data /var/www/html/sites/default`. What confuses me is why that would work. Beause before and after chowning, the permissions were `dr-xr-xr-x 3 www-data 6226 4096 Jul 20 09:03 default` for the default folder. So my understanding is that the owner, group, and others could all all read and execute, so why would changing the owner even matter?
Now when attempting to "Install from a URL" after chowning default, a loading bar appears and says "Completed 100%", and then this screen appears instead of the FTP login request:

[image: Install failed but at least it downloaded it]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I don't know why you get it's a file permission issue. The first screen tells you the Update module is going to use FTP; the second screen is telling you passwords are visible, since you are using FTP, not FTPS. it is asking you the user ID and the password to use for FTP; it's not giving you errors, but a warning about the passwords being visible. That would be true also when you log in on a site using HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: The modules directory needs to be owned by your ftp user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module directory has contested ownership. In your case, **using the FTP set up from the browser**, the modules directory (and subdirectories and files) need to be owned by the FTP user you are logging in with.

For example: if you are ftp-ing in with `myusername` then the ownership on the directories and files are most likely be `myusername`. That is the default configuration for most FTP servers (*ProFTPd* for example).

```
$ chown -R [myusername] [pathtomodules]
```

If you are **updating Features** (or configuration in Drupal 8) from the Drupal backend you'll want the modules directory owned by the same user as your web service runs as. Then you can have your permissions set to something more reasonable.
If you `grep ps` for Apache, nginx or httpd you should discover the user that's running the process.

```
$ ps aux | grep -i 'www\|apache\|nginx'
$ chown -R [username] [pathtomodules]
```

And finally if you are using `drush dl` you'll need the owner to be your SSH user.

**In all cases** you can set the strongest permissions with the following. Remember the webserver needs read on all files and execute on all directories. This command will give you 755 on directories and 644 on files.

`$ chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w [pathtomodules]`

The first two numbers in your `ls` command are user and group. That may be a numeric match for your web service user above. The third column is size.

Comment: there was no "httpd" process, only an apache2 process, so grepping for "apache2" gave me the user "www-data". So I applied  "sudo chown -R www-data ./modules". But it still didn't allow me to install the modules. Even if it had worked, if www-data owns the module folders, that means that it will have read, write and excute access? I read that that is not a good thing. Is that an okay thing for modules?

Comment: In order for the install module feature to work from the web server it needs to write to the directory. In order for the web server to read modules installed it needs read on files and execute on directories (so it can see within them). So your permissions should be `rw-r--r--` for files and `rwxrx-rx-` for directories. I don't disagree with you that there is a security implication in that. If you are still having issues please send through a sample of the output of `ls -la [pathtomodules]` and ideally let us know what OS your server is. If you have shell you could `uname -a`

Comment: I've included the details for you. The modules folder has `drwxr-xr-x` permissions and is owned by www-data. This seems correct to me, it has no files in it though.

Comment: Okay, so, it's not the permissions... Because I just chmodded everything to 777 recursively and it's still taking me to that update manager FTP login page...

Comment: Try making a directory within modules called `contrib`

Comment: Ok so actually you need the directory to be that of the user you are using for ftp. I missed that it wasn't going up via the browser.

Comment: I tried making contrib, it didn't do anything. See my update. Also I found that chowning the modules folder to www-data allowed it to install finally, because the owner has write permissions, but it wouldn't work before even though it had wite permissions as a group. Ugh.

Comment: Oh I see, I just read your previous comment. So, why does that work? Why can't it use FTP if it has permissions on the folder, why does it need to be the owner of the folder?
Also, thanks for the help. I still don't understand why it needed to _own_ the `sites/default` folder to download though...

Comment: Your permissions are `rwx` for the *owner*. If you are ftp'ing in, the default behaviour for an FTP server is to use the permissions of the user who is ftp'ing. It's not FTP server owning the folder, its the ftp *user*. I'll update my answer.